# Button not starting animation in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, image, animation

[Pictures of code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXwwx.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXwwx.png)]

[Pictures of code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B70aW.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B70aW.png)

Photos are attached. The latest textbook is from 2016 and I'm following the instructions step by step through the textbook.

I tried exactly what was in the textbook.